# Limits with sums and integrals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

It's one of my homework exercises that is rather problematic to me. Apparently the last thing to do is to squeeze it but I don't see yet how to do that. Could you help?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n}{k^2+kn+n^2}-\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}dx}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{k^2+kn+n^2}-\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}dx}$$

Comment: I suppose there is a typo in the formula.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! I have tried to improve the readability of your question by improving TeX. It is possible that I unintentionally changed the meaning of your question. Please proofread the question to ensure this has not happened. For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238).

Comment: @AméricoTavares thank you. The question is correct.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 3):

We can prove easily by change of variable that
$$2\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2-x+1}=\frac{2\sqrt{3}\pi}{9}=2\alpha$$
so we have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2n}{k^2+kn+n^2}-\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}dx}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{k^2+kn+n^2}-\int_0^1\frac{1}{x^2+x+1}dx}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{2S_n-2\alpha}{S_n-\alpha}=2$$

**Added**

\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2+x+1}&=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}}=\frac{4}{3}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\left(\frac{2x+1}{\sqrt{3}}\right)^2+1}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^\sqrt{3}\frac{du}{u^2+1}\\&=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\left[\arctan u\right]_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^\sqrt{3}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{9}\end{align}

We can calculate the other integral by the same method.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I need. Niceeee!

Comment: I saw another answer but it disappeared. That answer was correct but wrongly explained. There one must apply l'Hopital, not to factorize S(n) because S(n) can be viewed as a simple variable that tends to -beta.

Comment: could you add the variable change you used?

Comment: @PeterWormy Ok I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @PeterWormy You can see my edit and I hope it will be useful.

Comment: I thought you applied a clever substitution and got the other similar integral.

Comment: all is useful. Thank you.